# Using ItemLoader but adding XPath, values etc. in Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

Currently I'm using the `XPathItemLoader` to scrape data:

```
def parse_product(self, response):
    items = []
    l = XPathItemLoader(item=MyItem(), response=response)
    l.default_input_processor = MapCompose(lambda v: v.split(), replace_escape_chars)
    l.default_output_processor = Join()
    l.add_xpath('name', 'div[2]/header/h1/text()')
    items.append(l.load_item())
    return items
```

and needed the `v.split()` to get rid of some spaces - that's working fine.

But how can I add a time now?

```
l.add_value('time', time())
```

only results in an error:

> exceptions.AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are setting a default input and output processors which are applied for all item fields including `time` which is a `float`.

You have multiple options:

- instead of default processors, use field-specific processors:

  ```
  l.name_in = MapCompose(lambda v: v.split(), replace_escape_chars)
  l.name_out = Join()
  ```
- convert/format the time into string:

  ```
  l.add_value('time', str(time()))
  ```
- leave the default processors as is and configure an `Identity` input and output processor:

  ```
  l.time_in = Identity()
  l.time_out = Identity()
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much .. I read about the _in and _out but couldn't imagine how it would look like.